# When/how can I use Denore or Inoph bottles?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

I am currently at the end of the game, knocking out side quests before the final dungeon. I have a number of Inoph bottles and the Endless Denore Bottle, which seem like they would be helpful in running around the world to do sidequests. However, for the entire game I have never been able to use these bottles; note the lack of a Confirm option in the image below.

Is there something special I need to do to use them? Do I have to be in combat or something?

[image: menu showing Inoph Bottle selected but no Confirm option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate them by pressing the L2 button or your equivalent of that (for example V on a keyboard). Using them through the item menu is not possible.
[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/429660/discussions/0/3057365873431688582/)

This information is also available in the in-game help.
[image: How to use denore bottles]
[image: How to use inoph bottles]